# Slow performance spring.io flow from ActiveMQ to OracleAQ with XA

Tags: spring-integration, jta, xa, oracle-aq

I have a Spring integration flow which bridges from ActiveMQ to OracleAQ.
See example project under GitHub - https://github.com/cknzl2014/springio-ora-xa/tree/atomikos.

When I run it without XA, it is blazingly fast.
With XA, it processes only 1 to 2 messages per second.
When profiling the application, I see that for every message a new physical connection is established, and with this, the metadata query is issued on the oracle db.
But I don't understand why it does this, and how I can prevent this from happening.

Does anyone of you guys have experience with OracleAQ and XA?
Could this be a problem with the XA transaction manager (I use Atomikos)?

Thanks for your help,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

We found a solution to the problem.
It consists of four steps.

**Step 1: Use the latest Oracle client libraries**
The first step ist to use the lastest Oracle 12c client libraries.
There were significant improvements in the ojdbc8.jar, e.g. they use stored procedures to get the metadata now.
This increased the throughput to about 10 msgs/s.

**Step 2: Setup connection pooling correctly**
The second step was improving the connection pooling according to article  http://thinkfunctional.blogspot.ch/2012/05/atomikos-and-oracle-aq-pooling-problem.html:

```
<bean id="oraXaDataSource" primary="true"
    class="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="${oracle.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${oracle.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${oracle.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosOraclaDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.boot.jta.atomikos.AtomikosDataSourceBean">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="xaOracleAQ" />
    <property name="xaDataSource" ref="oraXaDataSource" />
    <property name="poolSize" value="5" />
</bean>

<bean id="OracleAQConnectionFactory" class="oracle.jms.AQjmsFactory" factory-method="getConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="atomikosOraclaDataSource" />
</bean>
```

This configuration alone resultet in exceptions because of 'auto-commit' of the Oracle connection.

**Step 3: Set autoCommit to false**
The third step was to set the following java system property (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_AUTOCOMMIT):

```
-DautoCommit=false
```

But then the throughput went down to 1 to 2 msg/s again.

**Step 4: Set oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant to false**
The last step was to set the following java system property (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_AUTO_COMMIT_SPEC_COMPLIANT):

```
-Doracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant=false
```

Now we get a throughput of 80 msgs/s.

**Conclusion**
The setting of `oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant` to false is not elegant, but solved the problem.
We have to investigate further to see how we can get around this problem without setting `oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant` to false.

***Many thanks to [Dani Steinmann (stonie)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638413/daniel-steinmann) for the help!***

P.S.: I updated the sample project under GitHub - https://github.com/cknzl2014/springio-ora-xa/tree/atomikos.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be sure that you use [pool](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-datasource) for JDBC connections.

On the other hand you may consider to use `ChainedTransactionManager` isntead of XA for two target transaction managers - [JMS and JDBC](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html).

Also see some information in the [JDBC extensions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datasource.html) project.

There is also some [Oracle AQ API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.streamsaq.html) as well in that project.

Comment: I read the [JMS and JDBC](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) article. Very interesting. Especially I like the _Best Efforts 1 PC_ pattern, which will be much faster but needs idempotent receivers.